# value `versionReconciliation` not found in set

Tags: scala, sbt, coursier

I have an existing Scala with sbt project. Sbt version `1.4.7`. I want to make dependencies check more strict according to next article: https://www.scala-lang.org/2019/10/17/dependency-management.html

I've added the next configuration to my `build.sbt`:

```
versionReconciliation ++= Seq(
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "relaxed", // "semver" reconciliation is also available
  "*" % "*" % "strict"
)
```

But got the error: `error: not found: value versionReconciliation`

My `plugins.sbt` is empty. sbt installed via [Sdkman](https://sdkman.io)

Comment: your build sbt version is controlled by file `project/build.properties`. What is the value set there?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc 1.4.7 as I posted in question.

Answer (score 1):

As the document you references states, to use this way you need to use [sbt-coursier](https://get-coursier.io/docs/sbt-coursier), i.e. you need to add `addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "2.0.0-RC6-8")` to be able to use `versionReconciliation`. Without the plugin you should be able to use the `conflictManager` key.